# is hoverIntent Plugin still the best solution to prevent hover flickering?

Tags: jquery, hover, hoverintent

Is hoverIntent Plugin still the best solution to prevent hover flickering?

https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent

Or are there better alternative hover functions for jQuery?
Maybe on i can use with .on();

Comment: Currently, didn't find any.